# Install software in different drive

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I've recently moved to Ubuntu 13.04 64bit. I want to install android adt into this os. But the problem is, the partition I made for this OS is very less. Are there any other options to install software into different drive as in windows OS. If there are any options please tell. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to move your `/home` to another drive.  Just make sure that you enough room on the new drive, and then check out [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).

**Note**: when dealing with partitions, and drives, make sure that you have a current backup just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use GParted to resize your partitions.

With Gparted you can shrink your Windows partition, Move your Ubuntu Partition to the left, and then resize it to make it fill in the extra space on the right.

I don't know of any other partition manager that can do this.

I also highly suggest you burn Gparted to a bootable disc, or bootable USB.  Gparted only works in a linux environment; and since you'll be moving the information on every hard drive stripe when you move your Ubuntu partition to the left, it would be safest not to run Gparted from that partition.